# RequestForUpdate always returns 400

Tags: rest-api, mobile, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am trying to update a Task through this code in a native android app

```
      Map<String,Object> fields = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        String id = "00Tw000001wvUCVEA2";
        fields.put("Subject", "A Subject" );
        try {
                RestRequest.getRequestForUpdate(getString(R.string.api_version), "Task", id, fields);
                TaskGridFragment.this.client.sendAsync(request, new AsyncRequestCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(RestRequest request,
                                    RestResponse response) {
                                    System.out.println("UPDATE RESP "+response);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Exception exception) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                System.out.println("UPDATE FAIL ");
                                exception.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

The problem is that I get this error

I get  BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Task/00Tw000001wvUCVEA2 why !??

Comment: Seems like a bug. But can you investigate the request is exact you trying to send.

Comment: I have changed the question, please help me :(

Comment: which release you are using?

Comment: I guess the last : 31.0

Comment: No, the volley library version you are using?

Comment: ... I don't know, how can i check it and update it ?

Comment: Isn'it in the salesforce library ?

Comment: No, It is android volley library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library previous to v2.2 have a issue: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues/449

You have to update library to v 2.2.0 at least. This is a bug in Volley Library.

Download the latest library from here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/

Or you can do this:

Go to src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java and change following lines:

```
 if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 299) {
     throw new IOException();
 }
```

with

```
 if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 405) {
     throw new IOException();
 }
```

Comment: I am using volley 4.4.2 and yet experience this issue

Comment: Did you tried to change the line?

Comment: I have a jar... Where is that src ?

Comment: you can get src from framework library link given in post. repace it with jar